# What are Screen.width and Screen.height values?

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2

I am currently working on mobile development on Qt. I don't quite understand the values returned by `Screen.width` and `Screen.height`.
I'm working with two devices: Xperia Z5 Compact (720x1200 resolution) and Galaxy Tab 4 (1200x800). But in portrait orientation, I have (for the xperia)

```
Screen.width = 320
Screen.height = 592
```

While for the galaxy:

```
Screen.width = 601
Screen.height = 962
```

So if the properties `width` and `height` of `Screen` are not the resolution in pixel, what are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The problem is the pixel ratio. A better explanation here: [Device Pixel Ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio).*

To find the real resolution try this:

```
alert('window.devicePixelRatio*screen.width: ' + window.devicePixelRatio*screen.width);
```

Or open this on your smartphone: [Example of screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio](https://jsfiddle.net/uusbugmf/1/)